# MySQL Insert...Select: Skip records with foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, constraints

I'm trying to copy data from `tbllicenseissued` to `licenses` MySQL table:

```
INSERT INTO `licenses` (UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate)
SELECT  UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate FROM `tbllicenseissued`
```

`licenses` has a foreign key constraint that is blocking the transfer: `licenses.UserID` is a primary key in `user` table

> Error Code: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`licenses`, CONSTRAINT `UserID` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `main`.`user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

If I remove this key constraint, the operation succeeds so I'm guessing that the data I'm copying includes ids that are not found in the `user` table.

I would like to copy the records that meet the constraint while ignoring records that would raise an error. I've tried replacing `INSERT` with `INSERT IGNORE` to no avail.

**Addendum**

I have tried all queries suggested in the answers so far, and I retried my own `INSERT IGNORE` above. They all give me the same error message (updated above to include the full error).

I've also confirmed that if I remove the foreign key constraint and try the query (on copies of the original tables), the query runs successfully.

To confirm my suspicions that the problem is `UserID`s in `tbllicenseissued` missing from `user`:

```
SELECT  UserID FROM `tbllicenseissued` a
WHERE a.UserID  NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `user`);
```

There were 26 records found. The table structures are:

```
DESCRIBE licenses
```

[image]

```
DESCRIBE tbllicenseissued
```

[image]

```
DESCRIBE user
```

[image]

I just checked and confirmed that all three tables are `InnoDB`

Comment: u can left join user when selecting, and set new userid value to null if not exists in user table, also new table should accept null values for userid

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I want to skip rows that don't meet the constraint. I don't want their data copied to the destination table.

Comment: ok ill update answer

Comment: If the inserts to the child fail, then get the data in the parents prior. Also don't do describe/pictures, do `show create table xyz` with text.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you do not want to insert rows that do not match.  If so, you have two solutions.  One does the check in the query:

```
INSERT INTO `licenses` (UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate)
    SELECT  UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate
    FROM tbllicenseissued
    WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserId IS NOT NULL);
```

I would expect `INSERT IGNORE` to also solve the problem:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `licenses` (UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate)
    SELECT  UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate
    FROM tbllicenseissued;
```

However, your question says that this does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I've tried both with no luck. I added some info to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, to skip data with broken user id constraints use inner join to users table:

```
INSERT INTO `licenses` (UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate)
SELECT  UserID, TypeID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate FROM `tbllicenseissued` a
INNER JOIN User u ON a.UserID = u.UserID
```

Comment: George I tried this too. No luck. I've added some info to the OP

Comment: please mention ur databases default one? because ur constraining from different dbs, try add databases to table references too

Comment: Good thinking George. Both DBs use InnoDb by default. I ran a test though; I put a copy of `user` into `test` database and set the `UserID` foreign key of `licenses` to point to this copy instead of the original. So all tables concerned were in the same DB. I then ran the query again. Same result :-(

Comment: hello friend sorry for being late, did u fix it?

Comment: No worries George. I could not fix it, so I (1) made a copy of the source table, (2) deleted from that copy all the rows that would cause a problem, and (3) ran the query in the OP but using the "fixed" copied table as the data source

Comment: okay so you managed to get what you was trying to achieve tight?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for checking!